# Check if member is new-initialized

Tags: java

How do I check in Java if my memberVariable/memberArray (of every standard type int/double/float... etc) is new-initialized?
What would be the difference to Double/Integer/Float?

```
class Class
{
    double[] memberArray;
    double memberVariable;

    Class() { }

    void init()
    {
        memberArray = new double[12];
        //memberVariable = new double(); //EDIT: does not compile
    }

    void foo()
    {
        // check here if memberVariable/memberArray has been new-initialized
    }
}
```

Constructing these in the ctor is not an option, the arraysize isn't known at this point.
And also I'd like to use primitive types here, not container.
This is an example, its not likely to be used in any project.

Comment: Do you want `memberVariable` to be a `Double` or a `double`? Because this affects the answer.

Comment: Well, considering this code wouldn't even compile, you wouldn't. Beyond that ... there's this concept of `null` in Java. You should look into it.

Comment: Various things: Please don't call a class `Class` - it will confuse you later.  Have you tried this in a compiler? What errors do you get? What have you done to try to fix those errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic types of variables that are given different default values as member variables (*when they are not member/instance variables they are not given default values at all*). The two types are reference variables and primitive variables.

Reference variables 'refer' to variables that are objects (*anything that is not a primitive*). All others are primitives.

Primitives are given default values of 0, except `boolean` which is given a default value of `false`. Reference values are given a default value of `null` which means not referring to any object.

So if you want to check whether reference variables (*such as your array of doubles*) have been initialized with any other value than `null` you can simply check whether it is `null` or not. Like so;

```
if(memberArray==null){ 
    /* Do something if it hasn't been given a non-default value */ 
}
```

If you want to check whether your primitives (such as your double) have been given a non-default value you can check whether they are different from the default. For example;

```
if(memberVariable==0) { 
    /* Do something if it's still 0 */ 
}
```

Be warned though, because you could give them a value that is the same as their default later. Alternatively Java has Wrapper classes that allow you to use reference variables to refer to primitives, such as `Double` (*Instead of `double`. Java is case sensitive*). That way you could check whether your `Double` reference variables were null.

As others have said though, better to create a constructor to **make sure** they get initialized with certain values.

Comment: +1 - It might be worth adding that using a `Double` instead would allow for a `null` check.

Comment: @BrianRoach - Good point. I'll mention the wrapper classes briefly.

Comment: `if(memberArray==null)` Thats what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use this pattern of construction and initialisation as your object is in an undefined state between those points.

Move your functionality in `init` to the constructor.

```
Class() {
     memberArray = new double[12];
     /*this does not compile: memberVariable = new double();*/
}
```

(And, if you want your code to be readable at 3am during debugging then rename `Class` to something else less keyword-like).

Alternatively, you can do away with the constructor altogether and initialise the members:

```
    double[] memberArray = new double[12];
    double memberVariable; // no need to initialise: Java sets to zero (unlike C)
```

Either of these methods means that you don't need to check whether or not something is initialised because it *always will be*.

**Finally**, if you don't know the array size in advance then use a constructor with an argument:

```
Class(int size)
{
    memberArray = new double[size];
}
```

and call this using `Class foo = new Class(12);` to create an instance with 12 elements in the array.

Comment: "Java has constructors for a reason" - My answer that is now obsolete

Comment: I can't construct it in the ctor because the size of the array is not known at this point.

Comment: @Bathsheba I caught your edit right as I posted the comment :)

Comment: Long story short: it is NOT possible to say if a primitive member array variable has been initialized or not or do they default to 0/0.0/false etc? EDIT: just read Rudis answer, so I have to check the array against null..